# Rails 3: How to create a new nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The [Getting Started Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) kind of glosses over this part since it doesn't implement the "new" action of the Comments controller. In my application, I have a book model that has many chapters:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chapters
end

class Chapter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

In my routes file:

```
resources :books do
  resources :chapters
end
```

Now I want to implement the "new" action of the Chapters controller:

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  # /books/1/chapters/new
  def new
    @chapter = # this is where I'm stuck
    respond_with(@chapter)
  end
```

What is the right way to do this? Also, What should the view script (form) look like?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

First you have to find the respective book in your chapters controller to build a chapter for him. You can do your actions like this:

```
class ChaptersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  # /books/1/chapters/new
  def new
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @chapter = @book.chapters.build
    respond_with(@chapter)
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @chapter = @book.chapters.build(params[:chapter])
    if @chapter.save
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

In your form, new.html.erb

```
form_for(@chapter, :url=>book_chapters_path(@book)) do
   .....rest is the same...
```

or you can try a shorthand

```
form_for([@book,@chapter]) do
    ...same...
```

Comment: For refactoring the code - one can also use get_book method to find book @book = Book.find(params[:book_id]) and then use this method as a before filter. This is because any method you implement in chapter controller would need the book object it belongs to.

Comment: Re: the comment above, if you had multiple children of book, you'd refactor the `get_book` method into `BookHelper` and `include BookHelper` in your books controller and books related controllers.

Comment: This dont create an extra select query to db?

Comment: What are you referring to @ArnoldRoa ?

Answer (score 6):

Try `@chapter = @book.build_chapter`. When you call `@book.chapter`, it's nil. You can't do `nil.new`.

*EDIT*: I just realized that book most likely has_many chapters... the above is for has_one. You should use `@chapter = @book.chapters.build`. The chapters "empty array" is actually a special object that responds to `build` for adding new associations.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps unrelated, but from this question's title you might arrive here looking for how to do something slightly different.

Lets say you want to do `Book.new(name: 'FooBar', author: 'SO')` and you want to split some metadata into a separate model, called `readable_config` which is polymorphic and stores `name` and `author` for multiple models.

How do you accept `Book.new(name: 'FooBar', author: 'SO')` to build the `Book` model and also the `readable_config` model **(which I would, perhaps mistakenly, call a 'nested resource')**

This can be done as so:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :readable_config, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true, validate: true
  delegate: :name, :name=, :author, :author=, :to => :readable_config

  def readable_config
    super ? super : build_readable_config
  end
end
```