# pass variables to controll and save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

I'm able to pass the variables to the controller but I think my method is incorrect. I have Referrals where a reply can be applied to a referral, in the routes I have nested the replies inside referrals.

I'm trying to just pass the user.id and referral.id to replies controller and write it to the db. The User.id is writing but I can't get both variables to go into the Database.

I checked and the two variables are going into the Controller, I'm just not doing the method right. I tried so many combinations but I'm confused.

**Replies Controller**

```
  class RepliesController < ApplicationController
     def new
      @user_id = params[:user_id]
      @user_id.to_s
      @reply = Reply.new
      @referral = Referral.find(params[:referral_id])
      @reply = @referral.replies.build(@user_id, :referral_id)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @reply.save
          format.html { redirect_to referrals_path, notice: 'Replied' }
        else
          format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**Routes**

```
    resources :referrals do
      resources :replies
    end
```

**button to reply on a referral**
This is the partial that is populating the referrals on the index page

```
  = link_to '<i class="icon-ok"> Reply</i>'.html_safe, new_referral_reply_path(:referral_id => referral.id, :replier_id => current_user.id)
```

Trying to achieve a "likes" for "posts" type of method but having the id of the user and referral in the reply table. Basically I need to pass the two Params into the db from the link

Now I'm getting this error on (http:// local host :3000/referrals/1/replies/new?user_id=2)

NoMethodError in RepliesController#new

undefined method `stringify_keys' for "2":String
Rails.root: /Users/laszlo/Documents/rails_projects/GemPort

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/replies_controller.rb:7:in `new'

Comment: Looks like a nested ressource. Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784183/rails-3-how-to-create-a-new-nested-resource

Comment: What do you expect with `params[@referral]` ? also `current_user.replies.new` should certainly be `current_user.replies.build`.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this `@referral = Referral.find(params[:referral_id], params[:replier_id])
    @reply = @referral.replies.build(params[@referral])`

Comment: the params from the link come as a hash correct? how do I pass the hash over through the .new or .create?

Answer (score 0):

found out its easy just to pass the params into a column when writing to the db:

Replies controller:

```
  class RepliesController < ApplicationController
     def new
      @referral = Referral.find(params[:referral_id])
      @reply = @referral.replies.new(:user_id => params[:user_id], :referral_id => params[:referral_id])
      respond_to do |format|
        if @reply.save
          format.html { redirect_to referrals_path, notice: 'Replied' }
        else
          format.json { render json: @reply.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

This link helped me:
[undefined method `stringify_keys!' ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815697/undefined-method-stringify-keys-ruby-on-rails)