# NoMethodError when going to page to create new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I keep struggling with this sort of thing in Rails.  I'm trying to create a statistics record for a given city.  I guess I don't need to paste my models?  Below is the error, URL, view and controller code.

Here's my error:

```
NoMethodError in Statistics#new
Showing new.html.haml where line #2 raised:
undefined method `statistics_path' for #<#<Class:0x007faf5e172928>:0x007faf5e717ef0>
```

The path I go to is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/cities/1/statistics/new
```

Routes:

```
city_statistics GET    /cities/:city_id/statistics(.:format)          statistics#index
                         POST   /cities/:city_id/statistics(.:format)          statistics#create
  new_city_statistic GET    /cities/:city_id/statistics/new(.:format)      statistics#new
 edit_city_statistic GET    /cities/:city_id/statistics/:id/edit(.:format) statistics#edit
      city_statistic GET    /cities/:city_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#show
                         PUT    /cities/:city_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#update
                         DELETE /cities/:city_id/statistics/:id(.:format)      statistics#destroy
               cities GET    /cities(.:format)                                  cities#index
                         POST   /cities(.:format)                                  cities#create
            new_city GET    /cities/new(.:format)                              cities#new
           edit_city GET    /cities/:id/edit(.:format)                         cities#edit
                city GET    /cities/:id(.:format)                              cities#show
                         PUT    /cities/:id(.:format)                              cities#update
                         DELETE /cities/:id(.:format)                              cities#destroy

routes.rb:

resources :cities do
   resources :statistics
end

routes.rb:
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @statistic = Statistic.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.haml
    format.json { render :json => @statistic }
  end
end
```

View:

```
%legend New Stat
= form_for(@statistic) do |f| ###### ERROR HERE #######
  = f.label :city_id
  = f.text_field :city_id
  .actions
    = f.submit "Add", :id => "add-statistic", :class => "btn btn-primary"
```

**EDIT** added routes.rb

Comment: please add your routes.rb file,

according to your routes you should use, form_for [@city, @statistic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. As @nathan points plural form of city in English is cities so there's something wrong with your routes, maybe you renamed it? (please include `routes.rb`)
2. You have a route for statictic which is a nested resource of city, so for form helper you shoud pass

`= form_for([@city, @statistic]) do |f|`

Comment: @Michael Szyndel: Thanks.  Changed both these things but now I get: `undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Comment: you have to set @city in controller first!

Comment: Oops, thanks :)!!  Your suggestion + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784183/rails-3-how-to-create-a-new-nested-resource helped me solve the issue.  Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Youre path file shows `citys` instead of `cities`. Perhaps you were bitten by an ActiveResource pluralize problem?

Comment: Don't mind the downvote, but please explain how it's incorrect.

Comment: Explained in my answer. Downvoted just for order so my answer is seen by the author of the question