# Rails -- how to structure belongs_to/has_many associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty simple question, I think: so I have a `User` model, a `Product` model, and a `Comment` model. I want the Users to be able to comment on specific products (like leave reviews for the products).

Is this the correct structure?

```
User
  has_many :comments

Product
  has_many :comments

Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's correct if you want just comment on products, if you will comment on other model other than product, then use polymorphic association.

also don't forget to add `dependent: :destroy` to destroy related comments if the product is destroyed or the user is destroyed

in Product and User model add `dependent: :destroy`

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
```

if you want other behavior than this, there is other options, from Doc :

> :dependent
>
> Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is
>   destroyed:
>
> ```
> :destroy causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed
> :delete_all causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not execute)
> :nullify causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.
> :restrict_with_exception causes an exception to be raised if there are any associated records
> :restrict_with_error causes an error to be added to the owner if there are any associated object
> ```

Comment: Take note, check reserved words for your database, you may not want to have a table called comments under Oracle for example (see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name/class)

Comment: @dosadnizub to be honest i have no idea about this, but for this example i think most rails developers use mysql, postgres, sqlite... and "comments" is permitted in the majority of databases providers, so i'm not sure why oracle is exception ! second thing, your link don't explains this, it explains table_name !!!

Comment: it's just a link on how to use different table name for a model class :) It's generally good practice to avoid using reserved words for columns and tables, comment is reserved under at least one DB so something to look for

Comment: Question: If a comment just `belonged_to` a User, then I could instantiate a comment by: `@comment = user.comments.build(content: "Lorem ipsum")`. However, how do I do this if the comment belongs to two models (the `User` and the `Product`)? Should I just use: `@comment = product.comments.build(content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id)`?

Comment: yes you can do this product.comments.build(content: "lorem ipsum", user_id: user.id), but i think if you are using a form, this should be set via mass assignment, for example in rails 3 you can do something like product.comments.build(params[:product]) then you set @comment.user = current_user, in rails 4 it's the same step but just params[:product] should be params.require(:comment).permit(:content)

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, except the `create` action that this is all going in is my `CommentsController`. If in the `create` method, I do `@comment = current_user.comments.build...`, how do I access the associated `product` to set `@comment.product`?

Comment: Alternatively, how do I do `product.comments.build(params[:product])` if I am in the Comments controller? (i.e. how do I get the `product.`?

Comment: i think that it's more convenient to use the first method, normally you have a product and a comment on this product, so your route should be nested like this  resources :products do resources :comments end, with this your form will post to something like /products/5/comments, with this you have the id of product which is 5, and you know the current user, so its better to use @product.comments.build(params[:product])

Comment: Oh sorry I'm pretty new to rails, so I didn't even know you could nest resources... I have them just listed one under another right now.

Comment: So if I nest the comments resource inside of the products resource, then what exactly will I be able to do? Will I be able to access the instance variables specified by the products controller, inside of the comments controller?

Comment: Also, another thing, sorry: before, in my `show` view for the Products controller, I had `<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>`. Now, after nesting the routes, I'm getting a `undefined method 'comments_path' ` error. What should the correct instance variable be now?

Comment: yes with nested resource you post to  /products/:id/comments, so you can find the product by `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` then use it here :`@comment = @product.comments.build(params[:product])`...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43875/discussion-between-medbo-and-ryan-yu)

Comment: you should have `form_for [@product, @comment`] , `@product` is the product you comment on, `@comment` is `@product.comments.build`, here is an similar example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784183/rails-3-how-to-create-a-new-nested-resource