# Get id of an object to pass into form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to find my time sheet id to pass into a form_for

here is my controller

```
def show

    @time_id = current_user.time_sheets.find(params[:id])
    if current_user

      @current = current_user.time_sheets
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
    end

  end
```

This is my form_for in my view:

```
<%= form_for(:entry, :url => {:controller => Entry, :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Subject form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:order_number) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time In</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:time_in) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Out</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:time_out) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Time Sheet ID</th>
        <td><%= f.hidden_field :time_sheet_id, value: @time_id.id %></td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Add Entry") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

What needs to happen is that the timesheet id needs to get passed into the form_for so the entry can have the timesheet id.

I have user, timesheets and entries.  user has_many time sheets, timesheets belongs to users and users have many time sheets.  Entry belongs to timesheet.

I am getting this error "Couldn't find TimeSheet without an ID"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "Nested Resources", eg. see here: [Rails 3: How to create a new nested resource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784183/rails-3-how-to-create-a-new-nested-resource)
You could use form_for([@timesheet, @entry]) to pass the id of the timesheet without using a hidden field. If you do this, the :url param also become obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<%= @time_id.id %>
```

to output your variable and make sure it's exactly what you think it is. If @time_id is a timesheet, you should probably rename that variable to @time_sheet.